# Randomising bidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

i'm trying to create a random bidimensional array, like an board for a game.
So far, i've done this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char test[5]=
    {
       '.', 'C', 'm', 's', 'e',
    };
    int i, j, r;
    char tab[10][10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            r = rand() %5;
            tab[i][j] = test[r];
        }
    }
    printf("%c ",tab[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to run this, the only thing that I get in the console is a "V".
Thanks.

Comment: Probably a typo, but you refer to variable: `teste` but the variable declared is named `test`

Comment: `printf("%c ",tab[i][j]);` move into inside of loop.

Comment: BLUEPIXY's comment is the answer as well, since you refer to `tab[i][j]` after the loop where i is larger than 5 and j the same. Which is a location that is not initialized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have your printf outside the loop, so its printing only the last entry. So bring in your printf into the loop as below:

```
for (i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (j=1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        r = rand() %5;
        tab[i-1][j-1] = teste[r];
        printf("%c ",tab[i-1][j-1]);
    }
}
```

Also note, Array starts from index 0 and not 1, so change your array assignment as per above code.

Comment: It is not the last entry. Look at the answer of @unwind. OP invokes UB.

Comment: You would be better to write your for loops like `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)` so that you can use the count directly as an index (without the `-1` noise). That is a much more normal convention.

Comment: Your fixing of array iteration is one of the worst. Why not iterate from 0 like normal people? Almost every i-1 is a first step to mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change like follow

```
for (i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (j=1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        r = rand() %5;
        tab[i][j] = test[r];
        printf("%c ",tab[i][j]);
    }
}
```